# How to create custom label for table column in element ui in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

I have a table with element ui and I have periods array:

```
periods: [
        { period: 'Today' },
        { period: 'Yesterday' },
      ],
```

And here is my table:

```
<el-table :data="periods" :show-header="false">
              <el-table-column type="expand">
                <template v-slot="scope">
                  <div v-if="scope.row.period === 'Today'">
                    //Do something
                  </div>
                  <div v-else-if="scope.row.period === 'Yesterday'">
                    //Do something else
                  </div>
                  
                </template>
              </el-table-column>
              <el-table-column prop="period" />
            </el-table>
```

And here what I have created in screenshot:
[image]

I want to add something custom next to 'Today' or 'Yesterday'. That means next to period. For example, I want to add countNumber next to it but I dont know how to do with prop attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<el-table-column type="expand">` is used for [expandable rows](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/table.html#expandable-row).

What you want is to customise the `<el-table-column prop="period">` by providing a template:

```html
  <el-table-column prop="period">
    <template v-slot="{row}">
      {{ row.period }} {{ getPeriodCount(row.period) }}
    </template>
  </el-table-column>
```

In your controller, define `getPeriodCount`:

```js
const getPeriodCount = (period) => {
  if (period === 'Today') {
    return //...
  }
  if (period === 'Yesterday') {
    return //...
  }
}
```

If you use Options API, `getPeriodCount` would be a `method`:

```js
export default {
  //...
  methods: {
    getPeriodCount(period) {
      //...
    }
  }
}
```